# Background process in Servlet

Tags: servlets, process, background

Is it possible to implement a background process in a servlet!?

Let me explain.
I have a servlet that shows some data and generate some reports.
The generation of the report implies that the data is already present, and it is this: someone else upload these data.

In addition to report generation, I should implement a way to send an email on arrival of new data (uploaded).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The functional requirement is unclear, but to answer the *actual* question: yes, it's possible to run a background process in servletcontainer.

If you want an applicationwide background thread, use [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to hook on webapp's startup and shutdown and use [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to run it.

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(new Task()); // Task should implement Runnable.
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

}
```

If you're not on Servlet 3.0 yet and thus can't use `@WebListener`, register it as follows in `web.xml` instead:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

---

If you want a sessionwide background thread, use [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) to start and stop it.

```
public class Task extends Thread implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            someHeavyStuff();
            if (isInterrupted()) return;
        }
    }

    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        start(); // Will instantly be started when doing session.setAttribute("task", new Task());
    }

    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        interrupt(); // Will signal interrupt when session expires.
    }

}
```

On first creation and start, just do

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("task", new Task());
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay.

Sorry. The request asked me is to implement a way to send email (an alert) when some data uploaded (new data loaded in DB). 

I had thought to implement this mechanism by modifying existing web application, creating background process that polling on new data. 

The data are loaded by some other application that I don't manage. Servlet container is Tomcat.

Thanks for answers

Comment: Why don't you just write this directly after the piece of code which updates the data in DB?

Comment: Because I have not access to application that loads data: it is managed and developed by other people that I can't reach.

Comment: This thread isn't blocking is it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I was wondering whether this should be better done inside of an request scope like:

```
public class StartServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {                   
        request.getSession().setAttribute("task", new Task());     
    }
}
```

This way, the process is stopped when the user leaves the page.